# Why is branch cut needed in complex log function?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

(I asked this in chat but did not get helpful reply)

This is from Kreyszig Advanced Engineering Mathematics:

[image]

[image]

Where formula (3) is $\ln z = \ln |z| + i \text{ Arg } z \pm 2n\pi i$

> I can't understand what would happen if, say for $n=0$, we include negative real axis as well? I mean, derivative is obtained to be $1/z$ even at negative real axis, hence in particular it is continuous there, right?  (using 'a function differentiable at a point is continuous there')

> That is, Why instead of working with $\text{Ln } z = \ln |z| + i \text{ Arg } z$ ($-\pi<\text{Arg } z\le \pi$) (which is indeed a function in conventional sense), this theorem deals with, say, $\ln |z| + i \text{ Arg } z$ for $-\pi<\text{Arg } z< \pi$?

Comment: You can obtain a continuous (even analytic) extension of the logarithm if you define it on a particular Riemann surface (the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$) rather than on the standard complex plane. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_associated_Riemann_surface

Comment: Instead of considering principal angle (=argument) interval in $[0,2\pi]$ (as Kreyszig does), which is adapted to a "cut" along the positive real axis, consider it on $[-\pi,\pi]$ adapted to a "cut" along the negative real axis ; the issue is that you cannot decide whether take $-\pi$ or $+\pi$ for the argument. This makes a lot of difference for the logarithm (not for the exponential of course).

Comment: I think Kreyszig has made a cut on negative real axis only: principal value of argument is defined in book to be $-\pi<\text{Arg } z\le \pi$ @JeanMarie

Comment: @JeanMarie, my question is not where branch cut is drawn. I am asking why branch cut at all: Why instead of working with $\text{Ln } z = \ln |z| + i \text{ Arg } z$ ($-\pi<\text{Arg } z\le \pi$) (which is indeed a function in conventional sense), this theorem deals with, say, $\ln |z| + i \text{ Arg } z$ for $-\pi<\text{Arg } z< \pi$?

Comment: (?) In your last comment, you have written twice the same expression. One thing is certain, if $z$ is on a cut, you are unable to give a value to the logarithm. This is why the apparatus of Riemann surfaces ha been created.

Comment: @JeanMarie, no no! I have not written the same thing twice!! once negative real axis is included, second time that is missing. It may look same, but its not. And precisely there is my doubt: why the former is not discussed in this theorem whereas later is?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed ! The reason I see is that in the latter interval you work on an open set which is topologically well better whereas in the former case it is neither an open nor a closed set.

Comment: In fact, I would say that a good way to understand cuts is by working on their crossing. See for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3535166) of mine about such a management.

Comment: I advise you this excellent book: ["Visual Complex Analysis"](http://pipad.org/tmp/Needham.visual-complex-analysis.pdf) by Needham.

Comment: Is "your" function (I mean the one defined everywhere, not the one on the cut plane) continuous at $-1$? You seem to me (if I understand you) to assert that it is (for some complicated reason) but in the neighbourhood of $-1$ there are values close to $i\pi$ and others close to $-i\pi$. So you are entirely at liberty to define "your" function, but for the purposes of using the standard theorems of complex analysis it's not useful, the theorems only apply to its restriction to the cut plane anyway.

Comment: Isn't the issue simply that when you talk about a function being analytic on a set, you want that set to be **open**?

Comment: @HansLundmark, $\Bbb C- \{0\}$ is open!

Comment: @ancientmathematician, that's my question: we see that "my" function is not continuous at $-1$ by inspection. But, the method followed in proof gives $1/z$ as derivative at every point, in particular derivative of "my" function at $-1$ is $-1$, right? And if it has derivative at $-1$, then it is continuous at $-1$! Why this discrepency?

Comment: I do not believe your statement about the derivative on the negative real axis. There is a jump of $2\pi i$ and so the function is not differentiable.

Comment: For the same reason why on the Earth we have defined an international date line across which the local time jumps by one day.

Comment: @Silent: Is your point that you _can_ get a continuous antiderivative of $1/z$ if only you're willing to have it defined on a _smaller_ set than $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ (since the definition you champion is not defined at for example $z=-1$)? That is true -- but "smaller set" turns out to mean exactly, "small enough to leave room for a branch cut _outside_ your domain".

Comment: @Silent: Hmm, true... But the function isn't analytic on that set, since it's not even continuous.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to create a *continuous* extension of the complex logarithm to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. If the function is not continuous, it cannot possibly be differentiable. The necessary conclusion is that any supposed proof of differentiability contains an error.

Why is it impossible to create a continuous extension of logarithm to the punctured plane? By contradiction, suppose we had a function $L:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $L(z)$ is complex differentiable to $\frac{1}{z}$ everywhere except $z=0$. Now compose our function with the complex exponential, and apply chain rule.
$$\frac{d}{dz}L(e^z)=\frac{1}{e^z}\cdot \frac{d}{dz}e^z=e^{-z}e^{z}=1$$

So $L(e^z)$ has derivative $1$ everywhere. Note that this applies for *all* $z$, since $e^z$ is never zero, and we had assumed that $L$ was differentiable everywhere except at $0$. Now integrate to reverse the differentiation.
$$L(e^s)-L(e^z)=\int_{z}^{s}1dz=s-z$$

Let $z=0$ and let $s=i2\pi$, and while recalling that $e^{i2\pi}=1$, we get:
$$L(e^{i2\pi})-L(e^0)=i2\pi-0 \implies L(1)-L(1)=i2\pi \implies 0=i2\pi$$

A contradiction. So the function $L$ with the described properties cannot exist.

In case you are wondering which error was made in differentiation: It's arctan. Logarithm needs a branch cut because arctan needs a branch cut. You can put the branch anywhere you want, and on any point other than the cut, it will be differentiable, but you need to put it somewhere, and wherever you put it won't be differentiable. For the usual branch, arctan(y/x) is discontinuous whenever $x=0$, regardless of $y$.